# Email a 7 day agenda from a calendar

Tags: workflow, calendar, alert

I haven't worked with SharePoint in years. Is there a built-in mechanism for sending an email of 7 day agenda from a calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such build in mechanism. You might be able to achieve that with custom workflow.